# Mapping items-itemtags-tags tables with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, hibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Let's say I have this database design:

```
Items
  Id
  Name
  Desc

ItemTags
  ItemId
  TagId

Tags
  Id
  Tag
```

And I want to map it to the following class

```
class Item
  int Id
  string Name
  string Desc
  IList<string> Tags
```

Please note that I don't want to declare a Tag class, I just want the Item class to have a list of strings that represent tags.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you want a Tag class?it will be strongly typed and alot easier to implement...
Ref:

> IList< Tag> Tags;

override the ToString() to write the "Tag" property if that makes it better..

Comment: I don't want the Tag type since I don't see what value does it brings. It will be just a wrapper around string with no real value. Also, since I will need to expose my types to COM it will add to the complexity.